# Is there a way to do a Post request with R Plumber without specifying the variables?

Tags: r, plumber

Can I set up the plumber for me to be able to do the POST requests like the example below?

[[1.0,0.0,0,0]]  -- comma separated

You know, just the values for the variables, without having to specify like this:

test1=1.0&test2=0.0&test3=0&test4=0

I´ve searched the whole internet and couldn't find anything like this for R/Plumber.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) package might have something to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to send the params values as a list of lists or does it suffices to send single values?
In case of sending a list (or list of lists) you could send it in the body and manage the request in R.

```
{
  "params": "[[1.0,0.0,0,0]]"
}
```

In case you don't mind sending params as a list and rather use single values, you could send them in the url like:

```
curl -X GET http://www.myownapi.com/1.0/0.0/0/0
```

Note that the number of values depends on the number of variables you need to use in your code.
You can parse the url in *plumber* with something like:

```
library(plumber)
#* @post /<param1>/<param2>/<param3>/<param4>
function(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
 ## Parse values and do whatever you do with the values

}
```